# Get string from default values folder (No Locale)

Tags: android

[image]

How to programmatically get a string from the default values folder?

Comment: is that string localized ?

Comment: Nope, it's not. This is the point, I want to get string from this folder, doesn't matter which is the current locale.

Comment: there is no way to do that if the string is localized (without changing the locale of the device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that string won't be present in localised strings.xml entries do this in your default strings.xml:

```
<string name="my_string" translatable="false">Hello world!</string>
```

And when you use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

It will return this value.

Make sure your localised strings.xml do not have string entry with that name